# How to go boating on Pichavaram lake?

Tags: india, ferries, sailing, lakes, tamil-nadu

I want to go to boating on Pichavaram lake located in Tamilnadu,India.

Are there any boating services available in this area? Please provide information about the fare for boats and timings.

Comment: Er, is there actually such a lake? My research indicates there's a mangrove forest between two estuaries that you can go on a boat trip, but no lake.

Comment: @MarkMayo Yes, It is a mangrove forest. But we call it as a lake here in Tamil Nadu (by the locals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference, [Tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowUserReviews-g790280-d2408767-r212724486-Pichavaram_Mangrove_Forest-Chidambaram_Tamil_Nadu.html) has a review of it from earlier this year (actually several).

It appears there are two options for boating :

- row boat for an hour (160 rupees per person),
- or motor boat ride for 40 minutes for 1100 rupees total.  The motorboat can sit at least 6, so if you have a group this would work out quite reasonably.

Further reviews under that suggest the same prices, and that the boat guy can take you to see some pretty interesting spots.  There's also a warning to bring your own food.